# How to create JSON Array string given below?

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, arrays

I want to create and to send JSON Array string given below:
I am using JSON Framework, it can parse JSON array but how
to create JSON Array

```
{
"deferred": [
   {
       "API": "Test1",
       "data": "{\"uid\":\"16\",\"cid\":\"22\",\"watch\":\"12\"}",
       "timestamp": "12-01-2012 16:05:45"
   },
   {
       "API": "Test2",
       "data": "{\"uid\":\"16\",\"cid\":\"22\"}",
       "timestamp": "12-01-2012 16:05:45"
   },
   {
       "API": "Test3",
       "data": "{\"uid\":\"16\",\"cid\":\"22\",\"type\":\"n\"}",
       "timestamp": "12-01-2012 16:05:45"
   }
]
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Isn't it a Dictionary in an Array in a Dictionary? I might be wrong

Comment: you are right. I solved considering your solution.

Comment: @Dilip Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you - that's how StackOverflow grows and can help others. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

Leaving an answer to summarize it all.

As I mentioned in a comment, it is a dictionary in an array in a dictionary.

Dictionaries:

```
{
   "API": "Test1",
   "data": "{\"uid\":\"16\",\"cid\":\"22\",\"watch\":\"12\"}",
   "timestamp": "12-01-2012 16:05:45"
},
{
   "API": "Test2",
   "data": "{\"uid\":\"16\",\"cid\":\"22\"}",
   "timestamp": "12-01-2012 16:05:45"
},
{
   "API": "Test3",
   "data": "{\"uid\":\"16\",\"cid\":\"22\",\"type\":\"n\"}",
   "timestamp": "12-01-2012 16:05:45"
}
```

Can be created like that:

```
NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test3", @"API"
                      @"{\"uid\":\"16\",\"cid\":\"22\",\"type\":\"n\"}", @"data"
                      @"12-01-2012 16:05:45", @"timestamp"
                      , nil];
```

These dictionaries are stored in an array.

```
NSArray *theArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: dict1, dict2, dict3, nil];
```

or you can make a NSMutableArray and add dictionaries there right after creating them.

And that array is in a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *theBigDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:theArray forKey:@"deferred"];
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**SBJSON** is useful for the same. For better guidance [Tutorial: JSON Over HTTP On The iPhone](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)

SBJSON will work like...

```
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];  
NSMutableArray *ArrayResponse = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[json objectWithString:responseString error:nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

first you take your json responce in dictionary 
and than pass into array